# Crashlytics is not sending Crash report from iPhone

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, crashlytics

I've setup the Crashlytics in my one iOS application and installed the application on a real device. My Crashlytics Dashboard is displaying that, I've successfully added the app. However, it's not sending crash report. My internet speed is not so good. But I can check my emails from this device. Can anybody guess, where is the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Crashlytics service. Crash reports from the device are never sent (in my experience) - only from the simulator. I ended up using Crittercism crash reporting and error handling.

Comment: Same happening to me. Try your application with another device than actual development device, this way you can get crash reports.

Comment: Yes, I'm using my development device. Is it making the problem?

Comment: Without a complete setup description or test project this is impossible to answer. You should contact crashlytics support. Wild guessing doesn't help.

Comment: I'm so astonished that someone from Crashlytics saw my this post on StackOverflow and he contacted me by email; He's helping me to solve this issue. Let's see what happens.

Comment: My client has checked the app on his iPad. The application crashes... but the crash report never comes to my Crashlytics dashboard.

Comment: I have installed Crashlytics in our project too and distributed to about 15 people. There have been crashes, but no reports have been going through to Crashlytics.

Comment: Hi @farhadrubel, wondering if this has been resolved for you? or if you have got any help from the Crashlytics team?

Answer (score 109):

Xcode debugger does NOT allow Crashlytics to process crash reports. Yeah, that seem weird even to me when I read that first time but it is a fact ([Source](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)). That's is the reason we never see crash report When:
 - running app in Simulator
 - running app on iDevice by directly build and run from Xcode with debugger on.

To make sure a crash is reported during your testing ([copied from Crashlytics support site](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)):
 1. Launch simulator
 2. Press stop
 3. Launch your app and force a crash
 4. Relaunch the app from simulator
 5. See the crash report in the web dashboard.

EDIT:

Added a reference; Crashlytics also provides a short article on [a quick way to force a crash](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92522-is-there-a-quick-way-to-force-a-crash).

Comment: This helped me. I've also discovered that in some cases. Crashlytics will not send the crash report unless the application is opened up again. To reiterate: User experiences a crash. User reopens application. Crashlytics sends previous crash report.

Comment: @tambykojak this is likely due to the fact that iOS Crashes are quite volatile in most cases and the safer route is to send a crash report on the next app load versus sending it right away. Many Crash Reporting tools use this paradigm on iOS and other non-VM crash handlers.

Comment: Thank you. This should be marked as correct answer :)

Comment: Do i need to upload any dsyms in this case ? If so where can i find them ?

Comment: links are dead.

Comment: This is still a valid answer, thx and +1 upvote or it.

Comment: +1 as this solved my issue. I didn't run my app on the Simulator though, I ran it on my physical device in profile mode (Run > Profile in Android Studio), stopped the app, unplugged the device, restarted the app, triggered the crash via a button and then restarted the app. Note that profile mode is necessary as it allows you to restart the app many times on your device (something you can't do in the standard debug mode).

Answer (score 72):

My be it's late but work 100%

Make some changes in project build settings like in below image

[image]

[and follow these instructions.](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)

Comment: Even after disabling Bitcode, I was still having missing dSYMS errors every now and then, and 100% of the time when debugging with the simulator. This fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: By changing this setting I was able to see crashes in firebase platform

Comment: Thank you! That did it!

Answer (score 23):

The primary reason any crash reporter won't work on iOS is due to interference from different crash reporters. However, with Crashlytics specifically there could be something specific to them causing the crash report not getting reported.

Xcode debugger does NOT allow **Any Crash Reporter** to process crash reports. This is because XCode overrides any hooks into the crash handling call backs. This only happens when:

- running app in Simulator (with debugger on)
- running app on iDevice by directly build and run from Xcode with debugger on.

To make sure a crash is reported during your testing (http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-):

1. Launch simulator
2. Press stop
3. Launch your app and force a crash
4. Relaunch the app from simulator
5. See the crash report in the web dashboard.

While a super old video it's still relevant, here's a video of the steps above (example from Crittercism): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU6Su3PBFH4

Comment: Crashlytics disables itself when it detects a debugger attached. Not because it will not work, but because it will stop the *debugger* from working correctly. Crashlytics uses the same mechanisms the debugger itself uses, and it would be really frustrating for the SDK to mess up the normal debugging flow. For reference, I wrote most of the Crashlytics SDK.

Comment: god like answer wp

Answer (score 11):

For me, the problem was that the device was connected to my Mac :)
From [this source](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-):

> Also, if you have your device connected to your Mac, XCode's debugger
>   will step in as well. So just disconnect the device before testing :)

Comment: thank you for this!!!

Answer (score 8):

I found solution using following steps
    1. Go to Edit Scheme
    2. Run -> Info
    3. Change Build Configuration to release.
    Now run the app crash it. You will receive mail.

Answer (score 6):

We recently ran into this issue and I found that somewhere along the way the build script was removed. Adding it back in with the following fixed the issue for us:
`./Crashlytics.framework/run <your_api_key> <build_secret>`

**Note :** When using Cocoapods you will want to us the following instead of the above ([source](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CrashlyticsFramework/2.2.5.2/)):
`./Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/run`

Adding a build script:

> 1. To add a Run Script Build Phase in Xcode 6, select your application target in your project, then select "Build Phases".
> 2. Click the small "plus" icon and select "New Run Script Build Phase".
> 3. You should now see a Run Script section in the middle of your Build Phase options, as shown above.
> 4. Inside the body of the Run Script Build Phase, paste in the script.`

The above quote comes from Crashlytics's [visual tutorial](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com), referenced in [this post](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/117178-i-m-stuck-at-the-run-script-build-phase-stage-w).

**Note:** I originally posted this answer verbatim for [Crashlytics error code: 202 when Submitting files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27695485/2789144).

Comment: This seems to have helped me.

Comment: i used fabric previously for twitter integration now i want crashlytics also i added framework and i followed all instructions but i didn't get any crash reports to my dash board please help me

Comment: @iOS_Ramesh I would love to try to help you, but without knowing more it will be hard. To do this you should open a a new question outlining where you are at (the step you followed to integrate, any appropriate code snippets, and any feedback you are getting from Crashlytics or the console).

Comment: I Already post a new question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215049/crashlytics-not-sending-crash-reports-to-my-fabric-dash-board

Comment: Thanks for the hint. We had  [ "Release" = "${CONFIGURATION}" ] check in our Run Script and we have renamed our Release configuration.

Answer (score 4):

From the RayWenderlich site:

> You won’t get any crash reports if Xcode intercepts the crash event!
>   To make all the examples below work, you have to build and run the
>   application, then click the stop button on Xcode. This way you will
>   have the latest version installed on the the device. Once that is
>   done, you can launch the app on the device itself, and then crash it
>   all you want! All the crashes on your iOS device will be caught and
>   sent to the server component of the service that you have integrated
>   into the app. Crash reports are usually sent to the server the next
>   time you start the app, so the steps to follow to generate a crash
>   report on the server are as follows: Build and run on Xcode. Press the
>   stop button. Run the app on your iOS device. Make the app crash. Run
>   the app again.

Answer (score 3):

Crashlytics works for me until now.
I don't know why but now it doesn't work.

You should turn debug-mode on by

```
[Crashlytics sharedInstance].debugMode = YES;
```

My problem is here [Crashlytics error code: 202 when Submitting files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182532/crashlytics-error-code-202-when-submitting-files) :(

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are not forcing the crash too early.

Set `[Crashlytics sharedInstance].debugMode` to `YES`;

Watch for

```
Crashlytics] Settings loaded
```

on the Xcode console logs.

Then force the crash and restart the app, and the crash will be reported now.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem when trying the test crash code.

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

I was running my app from a device, without Xcode, and the crash wouldn't show up on Crashlytics Dashboard. What worked for me was the following tip from Crashlytics website:

- Make sure to launch the app after crashing it, so that the crash can
  be uploaded

I commented out the above crash() call, and re-ran the app. Then the crash showed up in the Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

This is for xcode 9, from crashlytics 3.4.0
[image: STEP1]
[image: STEP2]

After doing this, be patient and wait for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]` on a device and seeing if that gets reported? There are a few reasons why Crashlytics might not work including other crash reporters etc.

Comment: No, I'm using int *x = NULL; *x = 42; code to see crash report. Moreover, my app is also crashing for different core data model.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't upload the dSYM file, Crashlytics will not show your crash even though the report successfully uploaded.

You could run into this problem, if you have set up your build-script to only run on your CI server. Then if you have copied your app to your phone via xcode and you run it without being attached to the debugger, the report will be uploaded but ignored, because of the missing dSYM file.

Comment: As reference: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/121064-why-don-t-i-see-data-from-my-first-crash-in-the-da

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it takes some time for the logs to show up. I am able to find them after 15-20 mins

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue I feel that in the Run Script Phase, it should be a separate Run Script Phase for CrashLytics. When had the run script

```
./Fabric.framework/run
```

With some of my other script, everything was ok, CrashLytics log show report submitted, but nothing was in the web interface.

When I add another Run script phase only with Fabric run, it appears like a magic :)

My first try was with cocoapods, but that did not work. 
When I manually add all the framework and a separate run script phase  that worked.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me,

If you're testing on iDevice, just unplug iDevice with your Xcode and run your app.
Now, If crashed it will be updated on dashboard.

Answer (score -3):

I solved by deselecting "Run Script only when installing" option in Run script (one for Fabric(crashlytics))

[image]

Comment: That's just the script that uploads the symbols to Crashlytics; how that solve the issue of crash reports not being sent?  What steps to do you take to avoid using Crashlytics when the symbols haven't been uploaded?  This answer is misleading and just plain wrong.