# Crashlytics error code: 202 when Submitting files

Tags: ios, crashlytics

My app (**iOS**) used [crashlytics framework](http://www.crashlytics.com) and it was OK until now.
But in some days ago, I didn't see any report on crashlytics dashboard.

So I made a testing bug by `[[Crashlytics shareInstance] crash]` and it logged

```
2013-08-12 15:02:22.927 ... [Crashlytics] Processed file successfully
2013-08-12 15:02:22.930 ... [Crashlytics] Alternate file submission complete
2013-08-12 15:02:22.933 ... [Crashlytics] Displaying permission alert
2013-08-12 15:02:38.919 ... [Crashlytics] Submitting files
2013-08-12 15:02:41.585 ... [Crashlytics] Submission response: {status: 202, error: (null)}
2013-08-12 15:02:41.587 ... [Crashlytics] Submitted file successfully
2013-08-12 15:02:41.589 ... [Crashlytics] No sendable files, submission process complete
```

Now, my app can not send any bug-report :(

What happened with my app?

P/s: I have another Android app, it still used same key-crashlytics and it was still OK.

Comment: The log messages look okay to me. HTTP status 202 means "the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place."

Comment: Yeah, I known! HTTP status code is decribled at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html. But why is it? Maybe it is bug of crashlytics server and I can't solve it ??? :(

Comment: Maybe the dSYM file is missing. Crashlytics should automatically upload it to the server. You should contact support if you can't solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is missing of dSYM. So I changed build version and build again.... problem was solved!

If anybody has the problem is that crashlytics app (on MAC) was freezed, took so much ram, let clean cache at `~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac` (from **crashlytics supporter**)

Comment: My solution was to make sure the ```[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey]``` is the last line of the ```didFinishLaunchingWithOptions``` method.

Comment: My problem stemmed from running Pony Debugger. I commented it out and added `[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey]` to the bottom as well. Seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into this issue and I found that somewhere along the way the build script was removed. Adding it back in with the following fixed the issue for us:
`./Crashlytics.framework/run <your_api_key> <build_secret>`

**Note :** When using Cocoapods you will want to us the following instead of the above ([source](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com)):
`./Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/run`

Adding a build script:

> 1. To add a Run Script Build Phase in Xcode 6, select your application target in your project, then select "Build Phases".
> 2. Click the small "plus" icon and select "New Run Script Build Phase".
> 3. You should now see a Run Script section in the middle of your Build Phase options, as shown above.
> 4. Inside the body of the Run Script Build Phase, paste in the script.`

The above quote comes from the Crashlytics [visual tutorial](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com), referenced in [this post](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/117178-i-m-stuck-at-the-run-script-build-phase-stage-w).