# Is it possible to know the exact time of a crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I have integrated Crashlytics to my app. I wonder what is the timestamp shown? It doesn't seem to represent the time of the crash itself. Downloaded maybe? If it's so then how can I get exact time of a crash to correlate with logs?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818428/crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-report-from-iphone

Comment: How is it related? I am getting crashes. I want to know when they happened exactly to a minute.

Comment: Did you know in which line it is crashing? If yes then put [NSDate date] above to that line and check

Comment: @hussainShabbir, not sure I understand. It's a random rare crash. I have logs around that place and that's exactly what I am trying to figure out -- what log messages correspond to the crash. I do have timestamps logged but without knowing when crash occurred, it's hard/impossible to look at the right place :S

Comment: @Ramshad Explain please based on what you marked as duplicate to a non-related issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can, just go to the **Fabric** dashboard, select your **crash**, tap in **View all sessions** and you can see the timestamp near de navigation arrows.

[image: View all session button]

[image]