# Crashlytics not sending crash Reports to my Fabric dash board?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crashlytics

In My app previously used fabric for twitter integration purpose. Now i want crashlytics .so i followed as fabric guided me
 added framework to my project

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
      [Fabric with:@[TwitterKit, CrashlyticsKit]];  
}
```

later i added run script in Build Phase also
 checked with Force crash but i didn't get any crash report to my Fabric dash board ...Please Guide me Where i did mistake....

Answer (score 8):

Finally today I found solution, to get report with dubug mode make change like in below image.

[image]

[and follow these instructions](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)  [,like I have also post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818428/crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-report-from-iphone/33148470#33148470)

Comment: Thank you! This helped me since I had created my custom schemes, but forgot to set this setting for them.

Answer (score 6):

Where did you wrote code for Force crash?

You should give the code to Force crash in another class, not in AppDelegate.

You should run the app from simulator or device, but not from XCode.(once run the build from Xcode, stop it and then from simulator open the app.)

Comment: Thanks for Your Response. I added the force crash code in button action and  i followed as you said , and i click on Debug in that open system log also but didn't get Crash Reports

Comment: Wait for few seconds/mins you will get the crash report.
Last time i checked it took me around 20mins to get the report.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that "Top Builds" filter is removed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 7. By default in build setting -> enable bitcode is set to YES.
You need to make it NO. And then check.

This works for me. As per my Reading app need to send the crash reports to fabric. But if the Enable bitcode is YES then you need to download the DYSM file from Xcode and upload it manually to fabric.

check [Advanced Fabric setting](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html)

Also please check [more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404777/crashlytics-not-reporting-crash-in-release-mode)