# Crash reporting using Crashlytics Fabric not working after updates

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Referring to this post: [Crashlytics not reporting crash in Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404777/crashlytics-not-reporting-crash-in-release-mode/33506621#33506621) :

I have done every single change the original poster has mentioned already including the changes mentioned in the answer but I still can't get crashes to be displayed in the dashboard for release.

The only difference is that I am using Jenkins to make my release builds. If I run the app locally from Xcode (and of course stop Xcode and restart the app on its own so the debugger doesn't get in the way), reports are being recorded and displayed just fine.

I have also implemented the Crashlytics Delegate method to make sure the crash is indeed being logged and it is. It just never shows up in the dashboard if it is a Jenkins build.

Would anyone have any insight on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Jenkins, but the problem that happened to me was that I was using the Fabric Mac App to apply the API key through the setup process.

For me the fix was simply:

Go to fabric.io -> Organisations -> Your org -> API key

and remplace this:

```
 Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

by:

```
 Fabric.with([Crashlytics.start(withAPIKey: "YOUR_API_KEY")]
```

This way you can force Fabric to use your API key. My guess is that when Jenkins builds your app, it doesn't have access the the Fabric App and thus can not set the proper API Key.

Comment: I have moved away from that project since the question is kind of old but your answer makes a lot of sense so I will upvote it for anyone else that might have a similar issue in the future.