# Fabric Crashlytics is not send crash report after app was submitted to App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I use Fabric Beta to get crash reports with Ad-Hoc provision profile before. After I submit my app to App Store, I didn't see any crash reports in the Crashlytics dashboard. So everything is working when distributed by Fabric Beta, but not App Store?

Comment: Crashtlytics does not report crashes if the build configuration is set to 'Debug'. I hope you had set the configuration of your Archive to 'Release'

Comment: Hey @7vikram7 - Mike from Fabric here - we can capture crashes if the build configuration is set to 'Debug', you just need to make sure that dSYMs are created when using that build configuration.

Comment: Hey @yong_ho, Fabric can detect crashes on the production version of your app - are you using Bitcode?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thank you for the clarification. So if we upload the dSYM to fabric web panel, it would report crashes of debug configuration too?

Comment: Yep, alternatively, just use the upload-symbols script documented here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script

Comment: I faced the same issue, the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818428/crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-report-from-iphone) solved my problem, which is you have to run on the simulator... @MikeBonnell please advice.

Comment: @AhmadF It's unclear to me what issue you're facing. If it's a separate issue, I'd recommend posting a new question. I'd also make sure you've uploaded any missing dSYMs. You can check your app's settings page to see if any are missing.