# iOS - Crashlytics - missing several crashes

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, crashlytics, bitcode

I have problem with Crashlytics (and with crashes shown in Xcode -> Organizer) because I don't see many of crashes that I should. From testers I should have many crashes there but I don't have. I logged into iTunes Connect and get zipped dSYM files there and upload them to Crashlytics to see new crashes. But even if it said that there is one or more new crash after upload dSYM I dont see any new crash. It looks like most of crashes I dont see in Crashlytics. Why is that? I need to get logs/crashes from devices that runs app from TestFlight. I think with Objective-C and before bitcode it worked much better.

Edit:
Is it possible that in another tool (from 3rd party company) there would be crashes that aren't in Apple Organizer? I am asking if I should try more tools from other companies. Maybe some of crashes are because of memory. Is it possible that these crashes aren't in reports?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check your email for crashes? Because Crashlytics email every crash.

Comment: I disabled email notifications. Is it possible that I get notification for crash that didnt appear later in web tool?

Comment: Thanks @LiborZapletal. Are you still seeing a missing dSYM warning? It's important to note that you may need to wait several hours after uploading a dSYM to see crashes in your dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: @ToddBurner nope I am not seeing a missing dSYMs. It's crossed. I check Apple crash reports too (in Organizer -> Crashes) and no new reports but from yesterday there should be several of them. Is it possible that in another tool (from 3rd party company) there would be crashes that aren't in Apple Organizer?

Comment: @LiborZapletal any chance you can share your app's bundle ID so that I can take a closer look at this? If you're not able to share it on here, feel free to send it along to support@fabric.io.

Comment: @Alexizamerican Because  of client I dont want to share bundle ID. I contacted email support.

Comment: @LiborZapletal totally understand. Support will be able to help you test this out and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @LiborZapletal Could you also share a bit more info about process of reproducing this crashes? If app is just terminated by iOS because of high load it's possible not to see any report even when you connect iPhone to organizer by cord. Itunesconnect crashes - useless tool because many people just disable point "send statistics to Apple" while iPhone activation so usually nothing special is there. The main question: are you able to reproduce the crash on any of your devices?

Answer (score 6):

Fabric shows 1 crash 'row' for each crash, the number of crashes is in the same row. 
[image: crash_row]

But remember, crashes are only send to crashlytics if the user opens the app again.

You could also test Crashlytics by using:
`Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`

Comment: Thats not my problem. This is what I know. The problem is that I get few errors but I think many different are missing (not same as the ones that are shown). So I am looking if it is possible that some errors didnt get to Crashlytics (even if user reopen app again). Some settings that disable it. Or what about if app is killed by system due to memory .

Comment: Yes, it is possible that crashes are missing. I've had this issue one time with a iPhone 4s. The application was only crashing on the iPhone 4s, before the app was even fully launched, other devices were working properly. This iPhone 4s crash was registered by apple but not by fabric. This makes sense, because when the app cannot launch, it cannot send events. 
Maybe this will give you a clue.

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you have uploaded your **dsym** files to your crashlytics dashboard, Check this

[image]

Click on the encircled part

[image]

Then on your Xcode > Window > Organizer

[image]

Tap Download dSYMs, When the download is complete right click your Archive and click **Show in Finder**, then right click the package and tap **Show Package Contents**

[image]

Open the **dSYMs** folder, then you can just drag and drop those dSYMs to the Crashlytics Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is related to two things:

1. As Gerrit said in the other answer **crashes are sent to Crashlytics if the user opens the app again**;
2. **The crashes in Xcode** --> Organizer **are displayed only if the user sets on the share of analytics** with App Developers.

For more informations take a look at this link: *[Share analytics, diagnostics, and usage information with Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202100)*.

If people doesn't share the analytics you won't see any crash.

EDIT: I found that your problem may also be related to the debugger...for more information check this thread and see if you can find your solution here --> *[Crashlytics is not sending Crash report from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818428/crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-report-from-iphone)*.
I hope to have been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If the application is crashing before the like in your `AppDelegate` where you are setting up `Fabric`/`Crashlytics` then the crashes are not going to get sent through properly.

It may also be that the crashes you are experiencing are being filed as Out-of-memory crashes by Crashlytics.