# Unable to upload missing DSYM files In Fabric Crashlytics with Bitcode enabled to NO

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have Implemented Fabric Crashlytics in my project manually. And in my application I'm using an external device connection for that I'm using an SDK, so for that SDK I have set bitcode to NO in my project. Before It used to work fine and I used to find my crash reports in crashlytics. But all of a sudden since from a week It is asking for missing DSYM files, and I'm not able to find any crash reports in crashlytics Dashboard. I have followed  Fabric Doc and tried to upload DSYM zip files manually. But no luck as I got stuck in the same page with processing message as shown in below link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIHdE.png)

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Can any one walk me out from this?  Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You tried with multiple DSYM files, right? Did you try with a single file? That too give same error?

Comment: Check answer number second in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818428/crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-report-from-iphone/33148470#33148470

Comment: I have tried uploading single file but no luck #user3589771

Comment: Sorry it did not work for me, any more suggestions. Thank you @RajJoshi

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If you run dwarfdump -u PathToDsym, does the UUID match the reported as missing?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I has same issue and UUIDs are exists (command returned 2 rows - for armv7 and for arm64)

Comment: Do they match the ones reported as missing in the dashboard?