# Crashlytics: A number of crashes shown in the dashboard, but no issue found

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm trying to integrate Crashlytics to my iOS app, followed the steps in [Install Crashlytics via CocoaPods](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install), and [Force a Crash](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features) to see a crash in the dashboard.

Anyway, there is no issue found in "Crashlytics" menu with 100% crash-free users

[image]

but a number of 30 crashes shown in "Latest Release" menu with 0.0% crash-free users

[image]

This seems to me that the report was submitted according to these logs.

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.8.5 (123)
[Crashlytics] Running on iPhone7,2, 10.3.3 (14G60)
[Answers] Initialized
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
[Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.5";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.8.5";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.6.12";
}
[Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
    "flush_interval_secs" = 10;
    "flush_on_background" = 1;
    "forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
    "include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
    "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
    "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
    "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
    "sampling_rate" = 1;
    "track_custom_events" = 1;
    "track_predefined_events" = 1;
    "track_view_controllers" = 0;
    url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
[Answers] Logging events to /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E216B87B-9490-4BDE-9092-56FD77DE81CA/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.onemoby.onewiwa/analytics/v2/events
[Answers] Transmitting packaged events for 'CAE6E657-71AA-473D-944A-A45510D472E5'.
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id 'b2f013abc70a45438ee435dbe39e8868' for submission
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E216B87B-9490-4BDE-9092-56FD77DE81CA/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.onemoby.onewiwa/v3/prepared/6EEFC81C-A3CB-46AC-8F1C-7A0383159915.multipartmime
[Answers] Attempting to log app_crashed
[Answers] Transmitting packaged events for '62888FCD-CEDE-43C8-B58A-9D963ED64F94'.
[Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
[Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
[Answers] Finished transmission of 'CAE6E657-71AA-473D-944A-A45510D472E5'.
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E216B87B-9490-4BDE-9092-56FD77DE81CA/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.onemoby.onewiwa/v3/prepared/6EEFC81C-A3CB-46AC-8F1C-7A0383159915.multipartmime
[Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
[Answers] Finished transmission of '62888FCD-CEDE-43C8-B58A-9D963ED64F94'.
```

I have also checked [Trobleshooting](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html#troubleshooting),

tried to enable debug mode,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().debugMode = true
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    return true
}
```

and `ENABLE_BITCODE=NO`, however there is no any issue in the dashboard.

What am I missing?

**Edited on 2017-08-30 8:08 PM (GMT+7):**

`Debug Information Format` in `Build Settings` for both `Debug` and `Release` have already been `DWARF with dSYM File`, Crashlytics console also said that `Yay! We are not missing any dSYMs.`.
[image]

**Edited on 2017-08-31 9:18 AM (GMT+7):**

There are some issues shown when I have checked the dashboard again in the next morning. However, I tried to re-produce a crash again, the issue had shown in the dashboard almost immediately after the app was re-launched. Don't know why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818428/crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-report-from-iphone/33148470#33148470

Comment: Thanks @SalmanGhumsani, but `Debug Information Format` for both `Debug` and `Release` have been already be `DWARF with dSYM File` and I have also followed [those instructions](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)

Comment: Any news about this problem? I'm facing with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just wait a few hours.
I've been using crashlytics on production for years, and this is a pretty common occurrence. In my case you just have to wait.

I'm not sure why, but the crash occurrence is immediately shown, but the logs take a while to show up.

Another tip is that the crash is only reported when you reopen the app after the crash. Not sure about the automatically generated crash, but with normal crashes I always have to reopen it first.

Comment: There are some issues shown when I have checked the dashboard again in the next morning. However, I tried to re-produce a crash again, the issue had shown in the dashboard almost immediately after the app was re-launched.

Comment: When a dSYM is submitted, it needs to be processed through the Crashlytics backend before it can symbolicate and display crashes. It sounds like in this instance there was a bit of a delay to process your dSYM but now that it's processed crashes will appear immediately. Typically, there isn't a delay in dSYM processing and this shouldn't be a common issue.

Comment: With regards to your last statement, I've been looking at my logs and Crashlytics and it seems that it checks the cache at startup if there are any dSYMs to upload which is why you need to reopen the app first