# Getting Crashlytics DSYMs for debug apps

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting

How can i get the DSYMs for a debugged app (no released on the AppStore) ?...

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20286446/3744739) that the debug session is not allowed to report crashes and errors to Fabric, but after i disconnect the device from xcode, my crash logs are reported and requires DSYMs, how can i get them in this case ?

also note that i am logging non fatal errors using `Crashlytics.recordError(error)` and not forcing a crash.

Comment: follow these steps https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Make sure that you have Debug Information Format set to "Dwarf with dSYM" and that your run script is enabled to run on all builds to get the dSYMs uploaded.

[image]

Comment: you are a life saver